General definition of order parameter in many-body quantum system
Consider a many-body quantum system characterized by a triplet $(\mathcal{H}, H, \mathcal{A})$ of Hilbert space, Hamiltonian, and algebra of self-adjoint operators over $\mathcal{H}$.
Is there a definition of order parameter for this system? The order parameters I have seen have the mathematical structure of a section of a bundle defined by essentially a classical configuration space (e.g. spins on a lattice). However, not every system has an associated classical configuration space, so this is not general.
